# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use an SQL script to automatically add a schedule to and from every airport. Here is the code I have so far:

```
 INSERT INTO phpvms_schedules (depicao, arricao, distance)
 SELECT
        depart.icao,
        arrive.icao,
        ROUND(GreaterCircleNm(depart.lat,depart.lng,arrive.lat,arrive.lng),2) as Nm
 FROM phpvms_airports AS depart
 INNER JOIN phpvms_airports AS arrive ON depart.icao <> arrive.icao
```

GreaterCircleNm function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS GreaterCircleNm;
DELIMITER go
CREATE FUNCTION GreaterCircleNm( lat1 FLOAT, lon1 FLOAT, lat2 FLOAT, lon2 FLOAT ) RETURNS float
BEGIN
  DECLARE pi, q1, dist FLOAT;
  SET pi = PI();
  SET lat1 = lat1 * pi / 180;
  SET lon1 = lon1 * pi / 180;
  SET lat2 = lat2 * pi / 180;
  SET lon2 = lon2 * pi / 180;
SET q1 = ACOS(sin(lat1)*sin(lat2)+COS(lat1)*COS(lat2)*COS(lon1-lon2));
SET dist = q1*180*60/pi;
RETURN dist;
END;
go
DELIMITER ;
```

All in all I really need help fixing this error:

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`virtu259_phpvms`.`phpvms_schedules`, CONSTRAINT
>   `phpvms_schedules_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`code`) REFERENCES
>   `phpvms_airlines` (`code`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

phpvms_airports:

[image]

phpvms_schedules:

[image]

Comment: The error states that you are trying to update virtu259_phpvms.phpvms_schedules but you are trying to put a code that does not exist in phpvms_airlines

Comment: @twoleggedhorse But it does exist in phpvms_airlines. It's confusing me.

Comment: The column exists but the value doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to INSERT `icao` values into the `phpvms_schedules`. You need to ensure that the FK CONSTRAINT `phpvms_schedules_ibfk_1` is pointing to the `icao` column on the `phpvms_airports` table and not the the `id` column (which is where I susspect it currently points).

OR

You need to use the `phpvms_airports.id` values as you FK back to `phpvms_airports`.

Comment: Where do I set the FK CONSTRAINT?

Comment: I really need help with this.