# How do I create multiple records using one column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure of the best way to explain this, but I have a list of airports. I want to be able to take that list of airports and use the information to put into a list of scheduled flights to/from those airports. Here's what I have so far:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS GreaterCircleNm;
DELIMITER go
CREATE FUNCTION GreaterCircleNm( lat1 FLOAT, lon1 FLOAT, lat2 FLOAT, lon2 FLOAT ) RETURNS float
BEGIN
  DECLARE pi, q1, dist FLOAT;
  SET pi = PI();
  SET lat1 = lat1 * pi / 180;
  SET lon1 = lon1 * pi / 180;
  SET lat2 = lat2 * pi / 180;
  SET lon2 = lon2 * pi / 180;
SET q1 = ACOS(sin(lat1)*sin(lat2)+COS(lat1)*COS(lat2)*COS(lon1-lon2));
SET dist = q1*180*60/pi;
RETURN dist;
END;
go
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO phpvms_schedules (depicao, arricao, distance)
 SELECT
        depart.icao,
        arrive.icao,
        ROUND(GreaterCircleNm(depart.lat,depart.lng,arrive.lat,arrive.lng),2) as Nm
 FROM phpvms_airports AS depart
 INNER JOIN phpvms_airports AS arrive ON depart.icao <> arrive.icao
```

I'm stuck as far as where to go next. I also have this error when I try to run the code:

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`virtu259_phpvms`.`phpvms_schedules`, CONSTRAINT
>   `phpvms_schedules_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`code`) REFERENCES
>   `phpvms_airlines` (`code`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Just edit your existing question. Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131267/cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails

Comment: @twoleggedhorse I wanted to ask something different since no one would help me with the error I was getting.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The constraint phpvms_schedules_ibfk_1 requires the values you enter for column code already exist in the table virtu259_phpvms.phpvms_airlines in the column code.

```
SELECT * FROM virtu259_phpvms.phpvms_airlines WHERE code='?'
```

Is this result consistent with what you have in the first table?

Comment: Okay. That makes sense, but I do have something in the column code.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/V2a2l.png

Comment: What is the primary key of table phpvms_airlines?Or maybe the foreign key reference is wrong..Are you sure its code?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to figure out the primary or foreign key.

Comment: What's your mysql client?

Comment: No, I never use `SELECT * FROM virtu259_phpvms.phpvms_airlines` in the SQL. I never even reference phpvms_airlines in the script.

Comment: Column code in phpvms_schedules has to have the same values as column code in phpvms_airlines,the foreign key constraint demands it.THAt's why i gave you that select to verify it with the first table.And learn about foreign keys. http://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-foreign-keys-quicker-database-development/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35099/discussion-between-pon-3-and-mihai)